# How to fetch all the items form chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on small chrome extension. Here i want following :

1) When user clicks on my extension the current tab url will saved to local storage of browser. Am using the following code to do this :

```
   **popup.html**
   <body>
   <input type="url" id="urlfield" value="">
   <button class="submit">Save</button>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
   </body>

   **popup.js**
   var storage = chrome.storage.local;
   chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
   var url = tabs[0].url;
   document.getElementById('urlfield').value = res;  
  });

  var submitButton = document.querySelector('button.submit');
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', saveChanges);

  function saveChanges() {
    var result=document.getElementById('urlfield').value ;
    if (!result) {
    message('No Url specified');
    return;
  }

  // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
  storage.set({'urlname': result}, function(all) {
  // Notify that we saved.
  //alert(result);
  });
```

This is working fine.

2) Now i am trying to display all the url's stored in local storage on options page as iframe.
Am using following code to do this:

```
**options.html**
<body>
<iframe id="link" src=""></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
</body>

**options.js**
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
loadChanges();

function loadChanges() {
storage.get(null, function(items) {
document.getElementById('link').src =items.urlname;
});
}
```

From above only one url is displaying as iframe . I want to display all the urls saved in storage. Can you please suggest me how to fetch all contents from storage .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `storage.set({'urlname': result}` saves `result` under the key `urlname` in storage.local and **overwrites** the previous value stored under the same key.

If you want to keep a list of URLs, you can save them in an array:

```
function saveChanges() {
    ...
    // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
    // First fetch the array of saved URLs
    storage.get({ urlList: [] }, function (items) {
        // Push the new URL in it.
        // You should also check that it is not already saved. 
        items.urlList.push(result);


        // Save the array back
        storage.set({ urlList: items.urlList }, function () {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                alert('ERROR: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            } else {
                alert('Operation completed successfully !');
            }
        });
    });
}

function loadChanges() {
    // Retrieve the whole list
    storage.get({ urlList: [] }, function (items) {
        // Process the URLs one-by-one
        for (var i = 0; i < items.urlList.length; i++) {
            var url = items.urlList[i];
            // Do something with this URL, e.g. create an iframe:
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.src = url;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have used your solution in this way: document.getElementById('link').src =url; to display each url as iframe , but still it is showing only one iframe, Is am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Yes. You only have one iframe and just change the url that is displayed in this one iframe. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks!, It works. Using javascript appendChild it shows DOM Undefined error. Used jquery for appending child it worked for me.

Comment: I had a typo in that line. I was using `'iframe'` instead of `iframe` (fixed now). Thx for the heads up. Glad it helped.